# No access to composer vendor folder on Heroku

Tags: heroku, composer-php

I'm hosting a PHP application on Heroku which installs Bootstrap using composer. When I deploy my application to Heroku all composer dependencies are installed in the "vendor" subdirectory as expected.

I'm now trying to include Bootstrap in my HTML views with `<link href="https://[Heroku app URL]/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` but that results in a "403 Forbidden" error because I have no permission to access the vendor directory.

I have no idea how I can gain access to that directory to include the needed JS and CSS files in my HTML pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku restricts access to the composer vendor directory on purpose, seems to be "best practice". To gain access to selected resources, I created symbolic links (symlinks) in a public directory to the needed files.

Comment: Can you explain/elaborate the solution a bit? How to created the symlinks?

Comment: Creating symbolic links depends on your operating system, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). After creating a symlink you can use its path to include them in your HTML files.