# Failed to load resource php include html

Tags: php, html, css, heroku

My PHP Heroku APP is a simple `index.php` that says:

```
<?php include_once ('index.html'); ?>
```

My file structure is the following:

```
-index.html 
-index.php
-vendor
  -bootstrap
   -css
    -bootstrap.css
-css
  -creative.css
```

The problem is that when my html file loads and tries to access CSS files for example:

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

None of the CSS loads and instead there's an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

---

I tried to fix this by running `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` on my root directory but this didn't fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am looking at your file structure and your reference to the CSS. Wouldnt you just remove the /css/ since its not in the CSS folder? 

`<link href="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: yes sorry I posted the wrong structure initially just changed it.

Comment: Did you check if the permission's been changed after the command?

Comment: Double check if your file structure is correct. It looks right to me. If it still is correct, try removing the /CSS/  and see if that structure works.

Comment: @GoofBall101 I'm not an expert, so not ruling that out. But since the error is not 404, that shouldn't be the problem. (I'm not the op, btw)

Comment: @FirstOne where do I check if permissions are changed? And yes my structure is correct.

Comment: For linux `ls -l` should show the letters to the permissions. I don't know if it fits to your case.

Comment: @FirstOne Ok I checked: both css and vendor are included in the list of permissions. Just as folders though, none of the bootstrap.css or creative.css files appear, not even the bootstrap folder is included

Comment: It's not a recursive command. You have to check inside the directory.

Comment: ok yes I see it in there bootstrap.css and creative.css

Comment: You should be careful that index.html is not loaded before index.php - also see this, which might be the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287491/403-error-for-js-files-in-vendor-directory-on-heroku , same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786436/no-access-to-composer-vendor-folder-on-heroku

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you, changing the folder name from vendor to something else fixed the problem. If you want to link the post as the answer for credit I'll accept your answer.